# tweepy: RateLimitError when I try to extract 1000 tweets

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to get 1000 tweets with tweepy. I know there is a limit of tweets that I can extract but from what I have read it is possible to extract 1000 tweets using Cursor. The thing is that I am extracting the desirable tweets and append them in a list inside a for loop but everytime I try to break from that loop I get a RateLimitError. Below is the code I am using. Any ideas?

```
def get_tweets(api, context):
                
    cnt= 0
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q=context,
                           since='2022-02-06', until='2022-02-08',
                           result_type='recent',
                           include_entities=True,
                           monitor_rate_limit=True,
                           wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                           lang="en").items()
   
    
    return tweets


tweets_1 = get_tweets(api, 'Lakers')
tweets = []
cnt = 1
for tweet in tweets_1:
    print(f'TEXT{cnt}: {tweet.text}')
    tweets.append(tweet)
    cnt += 1
    if cnt == 1001:
        
        break # Everytime I break I get RateLimitError
```

Answer (score 0):

are you still dealing with this problem? I'm not a pro but maybe it might solve your problem.

What I'm doing is exactly what u did but a bit further. I think the problem is at "wait_on_rate_limit" position which is in my code is written in Auth section:
`auth1 = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key1, consumer_secret1)    api = tweepy.API(auth2, wait_on_rate_limit=True)`

```
def get_trends(api, loc):    # get trendings at US
 trends = api.get_place_trends(loc)
return trends[0]["trends"]

def scrape(numtweet, API, db, a, b):
  for word in d[a:b]:  # word from trending [0:5] and [5:10] (ref: check def scraping)                                          
    print (word)
    query = word + ' -filter:retweets'  # remove RT tweet                            
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(
        api.search_tweets,
        query,
        lang = 'en',
        result_type = 'recent',
        tweet_mode = 'extended').items(numtweet)
    list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]
    for tweet in list_tweets:    # appending section                                   
        username = tweet.user.screen_name
        text = tweet.full_text
        text = text.replace('\n', '').replace(',', '')
        db['trendings'].append(word)
        db['username'].append(username)
        db['text'].append(text)
   return db 

if __name__ == '__main__':
db = {'trendings': [], 'username': [], 'text': []}
loc = "23424977"     # US's WOEID                                                            
trends = get_trends(api1, loc)
d= [i['name'] for i in trends[0:10]]  # take 10 of US's trendings list                                           
db = scraping(200, db)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(db)
```

What I'm doing is getting the top 10 US trends topic ( loc="23424977": is WOEID of US), and from each trend, I will take 200 tweets, so basically I can scrape 1000 tweets per 15 mins